# Unable to render globe map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, natural-earth

I'm trying to make a nice-looking globe in QGIS. I've used the Natural Earth data (10m resolution, bathymetry, land, and land-area render layer). I then used the following projection:

```
+proj=ortho +lat_0=66.5 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs
```

to generate an orthographic view looking down on the Earth, clipped the vector layers to the hemisphere arc, and presto! Beautiful-looking globe. The final renders (produced out of the Print Composer -> Export as Image) look fantastic.

Unfortunately, now, two weeks later, I want to make a couple of changes, and using the same project and shapefiles on the same computer on (I am pretty sure) the same install of QGIS, when I try to render I get this error:

```
forward transform of
(-5956998.189934, 5954291.026034)
PROJ.4:  +proj=ortho +lat_0=66.5 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 
+units=m +no_defs +to  +proj=ortho +lat_0=66.5 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 
+a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs
Error: tolerance condition error
```

What happened? Why can't it render? How can I fix it?

Comment: Does it work if you turn on-the-fly reprojection **OFF**? It might help to reproject all layers to ortho instead of relying on OTF.

Comment: I've reprojected the raster layer, and clipped the vector layers (but not reprojected them). Oddly, I discovered I have two user-generated projections with identical projection strings (I think the script I used to clip the vector layers generated one)—the globe renders fine with one and fails to render with the other. Very confused what's going on here (but since I can use the other identical projection, I've got past the roadblock...)